# Structure size issue, claiming unrquired memory?

Tags: c, gcc, structure, sizeof, bit-fields

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct {
        int a : 1; // bit field sized 1
        double b;
    }structVar;
    //structVar.a = 10;
    printf("%d",sizeof(structVar));
}
```

**size of structVar is 16 at gcc compiler on linux machine. 
According to me it should be 9. 8 for double and 1 for int bit field.**

Any idea Why ?

Comment: Because the double requires an 8-byte boundary on your platform? Because `int` is 64 bits on your platform ? Because ..... on your platform (fill in the blank). Structure alignment/packing, etc... It could be any number of reasons.

Comment: Unrelated: I almost forgot to mention, `a` is `int:1` and therefore a **signed** bit field. That means one bit (in this case, the *only* bit) is dedicated to sign-state. Less that bit you have a zero-bit width bit field, which for all intents is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure is aligned (and padded) to size of its largest member - in that case, to `sizeof(double)`. This is expected (although not required by standard) and predictable. It doesn't matter if second member would be int, short or whatever, - as long as it is smaller than double, sizeof struct will be 16.

Structure packing may reduce size of structure. E.g. gcc allows to `#pragma pack(n)` to set new alignment for subsequent structures, so with alignment 4 it will be 12 bytes.

Reason is, if you'll have array of this structures, second structure will be unaligned. It may have performance hits or even failures on some CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because the double required 8-byte alignment, as the comments stated. But anyway this is completely implementation-defined (that's why sizeof exists in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of padding. double must be aligned by 8 bytes. Hence, extra 7 bytes and 7 bits are padded to this structure.

You can refer this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/).
There are compiler specific options to turn off the padding. But they are not recommended for the sake of compatibility.